# matrix multiplication: $A^2 = A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am supposed to think something geometrically and come up with a matrix $ A $ that has no $0$ on it and satisfies the condition $A^2 = A$.
On a similar type of problem where I had to satisfy $A^4 = I$ when $A^2$ is not $I$, I used the rotation through the coordinate system as any matrix would come to itself after $4$ rotation i.e. through $90$ each time.

Is it something similar in this case as well?

// Here I thought maybe I can use reflection through $y=x$ axis twice but that didn't really work as I can't get $2  \times  2$ matrix.

Comment: The ‘ideal’ MathJax command for matrices is `\boldsymbol{}`.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor: You really don't need to set matrices in bold. If you want to distinguish them from vectors or scalars, the case distinction is enough.

Comment: @anomaly Yeah, that’s why I didn’t suggest an edit and why I put ‘ideal’ in single quotation marks. Normally I share that tidbit, because that’s what APA stylistic guide (I believe it’s that one) recommends, and also because I’ve seen uppercase vectors and lowercase matrices.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a big deal either way. My main problem with it is that bold looks ugly. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This intuitively means that "doing it again" doesn't do anything new.  One geometrical example is:  Projecting onto a line.  If you take your space and map each point to a line, then if you do it again they're all still just on that line.